# How to cast a generic to the interface it implements when the type parameters on both implement a common interface in C#

Tags: c#, generics, interface, casting

Consider the following code:

```
public class Thing : IThing { }

public interface IThing {}

public interface IContainer<out T> where T : IThing { }

// This works
// public class Container<T> : IContainer<T> where T : IThing { }

// This doesn't work
public class Container<T> : IContainer<IThing> where T : IThing {}

internal class Program
{
  private static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    var concreteContainer = new Container<Thing>();
    var abstractContainer = (IContainer<Thing>) concreteContainer;
  }
}
```

On this line:

```
var abstractContainer = (IContainer<Thing>) concreteContainer;
```

You get the following runtime error:
`` InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'CastTest.Container`1[CastTest.Thing]' to type CastTest.IContainer`1[CastTest.Thing]'. ``

Also if you have Resharper, it complains with, `Suspecious cast: there is no type in the solution which is inherited from both 'Container<Thing>' and 'IContainer<Thing>'`.

Why does there need to be a type that inherits from both? Doesn't `Container<T>` implement `IContainer<IThing>`? Since `Thing` implements `IThing`, and `T` in `Container<T>` is guaranteed to implement `IThing`, it seems like I should be able to do this cast.

Comment: `Container<Thing>` implements `IContainer<IThing>` not `IContainer<Thing>`.

Comment: @hvd What, now you want me to actually pay attention?! Jeez, people ask a lot. Whoops!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Doesn't `Container<T>` implement `IContainer<IThing>`?

It does.

> Since `Thing` implements `IThing`, and `T` in `Container<T>` is guaranteed to implement `IThing`, it seems like I should be able to do this cast.

`out` works the other way around. `out` means that if the type implements `IContainer<Thing>`, it automatically implements `IContainer<IThing>` as well. Not vice versa.

It's called `out` because it can return something. You might have for instance

```
interface IThing<out T> {
    T Prop { get; }
}
```

Now, `IContainer<Apple>` would automatically implement `IContainer<Fruit>`, and `IContainer<Banana>` would also automatically implement `IContainer<Fruit>`. That works, because something which returns an `Apple` can be interpreted as returning a `Fruit`. But if you only know it returns a `Fruit`, you don't know whether that `Fruit` is an `Apple`.

`in` works the way you ask. You might have for instance

```
interface IThing<in T> {
    void Act(T t);
}
```

Now, `IContainer<Apple>` does *not* automatically implement `IContainer<Fruit>`. That's because something which requires an `Apple` won't be able to accept arbitrary `Fruit`s. But something which only requires a `Fruit` *does* accept all `Apple`s.

Comment: Thanks. This was key to helping my understanding, "...something which requires an Apple won't be able to accept arbitrary Fruits. But something which only requires a Fruit does accept all Apples."